# Is it meaningful\suitable to mark the derived class as movable while the base class is non-moveable?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Is it meaningful\suitable to mark the derived class as movable while the base class is non-moveable?

I know this kind of ***inconsistency is legal*** in C++, but is it ***meaningful\suitable in practise***?

***In general***, should I ***sedulously*** keep such consistency?

***What about this case***:when I intend to mark the derivd class as non-moveable and non-copyable, should I mark the base class as non-moveable and non-copyable, too?

I did several tests to make it clear.

Here is the [first example](https://godbolt.org/z/EWvEhcs3W). Since the base class is non-copyable and non-moveable, the derived class is non-moveable in fact through it has a move constructor, which is in my expectation. Tips: the code snippet below does not compile.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(){}
    Base(const Base&) = delete;
    Base(Base&&)      = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = delete;
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    Derived(){}
    Derived(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived(Derived&&)      = default;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived& operator=(Derived&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;

    Derived derived1{std::move(derived)};
}
```

Here is the [second example](https://godbolt.org/z/5jz5scxad). The base class is copyable and non-moveable, but the derived class is moveable in fact since it will invoke the copy constructor of the base class instead of the move constuctor of base class when the move constructor of the derived class is called, which is also in my expectation.Tips: the code snippet below works well.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(){}
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base(Base&&)      = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = delete;
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    Derived(){}
    Derived(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived(Derived&&)      = default;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived& operator=(Derived&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;

    Derived derived1{std::move(derived)};
}
```

***UPDATED***:

Thanks to @Nightlord, he found that [the code snippet above does not compile with `Clang`](https://godbolt.org/z/1ab47TrMe), which is really out of my expectation.

Comment: To be honest it doesn't appear meaningful to me at all to allow copying, but explicitly disallow moving already in the base. Why should I be forced to use a copy of an object if I don't need the original object any more anyway? Or if copying is expensive, forced to use dynamic allocation (then passing around a smart pointer of)?

Comment: I also can't think of a reasonable use case for a deleted move constructor, but defaulted copy constructor. It will forbid certain forms of constructing a `Base` object, but which exactly will vary between C++ revisions, which just seems confusing. I think in C++20 essentially only the direct-initialization from a `std::move` (or another function returning a rvalue reference), from a derived rvalue or a braced initializer list argument will be forbidden. Otherwise nothing is different from just having the move constructor delegate to the copy constructor.

Comment: @user17732522 What about this case:when I intend to mark the derivd class as non-moveable and non-copyable, should I mark the base class as non-moveable and non-copyable, too? The said base  class is likely used as an interface.

Comment: @John Why should these properties of the derived class influence the base class? A base class shouldn't need to know what derived classes are doing. If the base class is an interface for which it inherently makes no sense to copy/move, then mark the base class operations as deleted, but otherwise don't.

Comment: The patterns shown in the OP can occur in practice when writing generic container-like types and constructors should be conditionally deleted. E.g. [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional). Before C++20 concepts, conditionally deleting is implemented by conditionally deriving from different base classes. One of the base class would delete the copy/move constructor, the other would define it. The most derived class (e.g. `std::optional`) then simply defaults it (meaning it is either deleted or not). But ofc this is not a typical inheritance.

Comment: From a design perspective, it can make sense if there is identified *potential* for derived classes to be non-moveable.  Making the base class non-moveable is one way to ensure that code which knows only about the base class (not about any derived classes) triggers a diagnostic on any attempt to move an object. But, any derived classes that need to be moveable can explicitly enable that - and any code with visibility of that class can move instances safely. [Whether such designs are common or not is beside the point - the point is that the designer of the classes, not the language, decides].

Answer (score 1):

> I know this kind of inconsistency is legal in C++, but is it
> meaningful in practise?
>
> In general, should I sedulously keep such consistency?

Yes, I think you should keep the consistency.
To make a derived class movable while the base class is not, the base class cannot hold any data member, otherwise, the movement is not completed.

In the case your class does not hold any data member, you might be using it as an interface. Moving constructor does not work with such a case since the client only recognizes the interface (the base class) rather than the concrete class (the derived class).

Comment: Your second paragraph is new to me. Thank you. I will do some test to fully understand it. What do you mean by "To make a derived class movable while the base class is not, the base class cannot hold any data member, otherwise, ***the movement is not completed***."? [It works indeed even if there are member variables in the base class.](https://godbolt.org/z/s9fjsdadG)

Comment: @John hello, in your example, what the derived1 really calling is the "Copy Constructor" instead of "Move Constructor". 
The Move Constructor won't work because the "str" attribute is maintained by the Base class, and the Move Constructor of Base is deleted. Thus, "str" is not movable. 

Here are two simply modified versions to your example which show what I said.
1. [Not compilable after deleting the copy constructor of Base class](https://godbolt.org/z/qc1dqPcW3)
2. [The str is not moved but copied to derived1. The Movable class shows how it should work](https://godbolt.org/z/serff6q6M)

Comment: I'm not sure why it is calling copy constructor instead of compiling error. 
I'm guessing it is done by the compiler because some compilers show compile errors while compiling your example. So I don't think it's the default behavior in the C++ standard.

Comment: The behaviour of the two example code snippets is in exception indeed. Some compilers show compile errors while compiling my example? Could you please ***reproduce the phenomenon*** with online compiler? As far as I can see, ***there should not be any error***.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8W6h9svYP). I simply select another compiler on the link you provided.

Comment: I see. It's really out of my expectation. I am really curious why this occurs. I updated the post.

Comment: I think it's some optimization or fault tolerance done by the compilers.